# Jenkins stopped building jobs unexpectedly

Tags: centos, jenkins, maven

I installed Jenkins in centos 2.6 in production server and 
created several build jobs for Maven projects on Java and Groovy.
All build jobs were being built periodically. 
Suddenly it stopped 2 weeks before and all build jobs were stopped.
After I restarted Jenkins, it came to life.

Is it a common problem? How I can investigate the problem?

Answer (score 0):

look for jenkins logs usually located at /var/log/jenkins/ dir. It contains stacktrace of the exception which caused the server to stop.